# Emacs is ignoring my init file?

Tags: emacs

Fresh install of linux mint 17, fresh install of emacs 24 (via apt-get emacs24). Ctrl+h, v shows user-init-file has a value of nil. How can I change this?

I already have a .emacs file, located at "home/usr/.emacs". Its contents execute correctly, they just do not get executed at startup.

Comment: where did you save your init file? How did you name it?

Comment: my init file's location is ~/.emacs

Comment: I have tried evaluating: (setq user-init-file "/home/usr/.emacs") but it does not seem to carry over after a restart.

Comment: what is the content of your file? Can you open it from inside emacs and see its content? If so: try `M+x load-file RET RET` to reload it and see if this has any effect

Comment: Yes, it runs fine. (menu-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)

Comment: Oops, enter submits a comment I see. Those are the only two commands in my init file. Running the file as you suggested changes the emacs window correctly. But it does not persist after restarting emacs.

Comment: allright, then simply follow tripleee 's answer and it should run fine

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've not been clear. I already have created an init file (~/.emacs). It does what I want it to. Emacs just does not load it.

Comment: I am sorry but I think I cannot help you with that problem. I think you have another file elsewhere which is interpreted as you init file (like init.el) but that's just a shot in the dark... You might want to post your question here http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: After you start Emacs, do `C-x d ~/`. That will show you which directory Emacs thinks is your **home directory**. If that it not what you think your home directory should be, then do what you need to do for your operating system, to define your home directory where you want it. Try setting environment variable `HOME`, for instance. In the Emacs manual, use `i home direct TAB` and check the doc.

Answer (score 0):

The variable will be set only if you actually have an init file. As per your description, you don't.

If you are asking how to create one, just save an empty file in `.emacs.d/init.el` under your home directory.

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html and http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Init-File.html

Comment: hello, I already have a .emacs file located at /home/usr/.emacs. Running the file directly (M+x load file) works. But it does not automatically load the file on startup. Using .emacs.d/init.el as you have suggested has the same problem. It seems that emacs is simply not noticing my init file when it starts up.

Comment: Is your home really `/home/usr`? Maybe you should copy the contents of the `*Messages*` buffer to https://pastebin.com/ and post the link here.

Comment: In my experience, `user-init-file` is always set, even when no init file exists (in which case it defaults to `~/.emacs`), *unless* you have told Emacs not to load an init file (e.g. `emacs -q`) in which case it is `nil`.